Sabr extension with stochastic params
I recall reading an article that discussed an extension of the SABR model, where the model's parameters were suggested to be stochastic, leading to improved volatility surface modeling. Unfortunately, I can't remember where I read it. Does anyone know the name or location of this article?"

I think this question is too broad to be useful, and should be re-thought. I don't know much more about SABR than the fact that it stands for "stochastic alpha beta rho"; but that's enough to suspect that "stochastic parameters" is the whole idea, and the paper you seek is a needle in a pile of needles.
